# 2D opengl rotation causes sprite distortion

Tags: c++, ios, rotation, opengl-es-2.0, glm-math

I am quite new to using OpenGL ES 2.0. Also im using an iPhone and the GLM maths library. As I reference I have been using this tutorial a lot: http://tomdalling.com/blog/modern-opengl/03-matrices-depth-buffering-animation/ But I have found it difficult to find a 2D OpenGL tutorial.

I am trying to rotate a 2D sprite but the image is being distorted.
For example at a rotation angle of 0 degrees: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFsgM.png and at a rotation angle of 45 degrees: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8iuRd.png

**In my sprite class**

```
glm::mat4 projection = glm::ortho(0.0f, 480.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f);
glUniformMatrix4fv(projectionUniform, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(projection));

glm::mat4 newModel = glm::rotate(glm::mat4(), 0.0f, glm::vec3(0, 0, 1));
glUniformMatrix4fv(modelUniform, 1, GL_FALSE, value_ptr(newModel));

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
```

**In my vertex shader**

```
vec4 newPosition = vec4(position + offset, 0.0, 1.0);
gl_Position = model * projection * newPosition;
```

I think that part of the problem is that the image is being rotated without considering the aspect ratio im not really sure how to fix this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are applying your transformations in the wrong order.

Instead of:

```
gl_Position = model * projection * newPosition;
```

try:

```
gl_Position = projection * model * newPosition;
```

Better still (to avoid multiplying two 4x4 matrices together):

```
gl_Position = projection * ( model * newPosition );
```

Even better: Multiply your matrices in your application and do a single matrix-vector multiplication in your shader. You should probably also include the translation in the matrix.

Comment: I tried out your code and it seemed to fix the skewing issue. However, the image doesn't seem to be rotating around its center. http://i.imgur.com/C2oIM96.png Could you please clarify what you mean by translation. Is this moving the matrix? Thanks.

Comment: glm::rotate will create a rotation around the origin. To rotate around a different point, you have to translate that point to the origin, rotate, then translate back again. If your sprite's vertices are defined such that the origin is at the center, it is quite easy. You want to combine the matrices as follows: projection * translation * rotation. And yes translation is a change of position.